# Como llamo una funcion dentro de otra funcion en python

Tags: python

estoy intentando llamar una función dentro de otra función por medio de unos comandos de voz, pero la función no es llamada

```
def luzPrincipales():              #Función para encender el LED
    try:
        print("Encendiendo LED")
        dato = 'A'
        s.send(dato.encode(encoding='utf_8'))  #Enviamos 1 al modulo ES
        MessageBox.showinfo("Aviso de actividad "," Luces Principales activadas  ")
    except:
        engine.say(usuario+"No puedes usar el modo automatización si no cuentas con la red configurada")
        engine.runAndWait()
```

Esa es una función que esta determinada en las primeras líneas de mi código, mi objetivo es llamarla en otra función mas abajo,

```
def EscucharNevy():
    r = sr.Recognizer() 
    while True:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('Hola, soy tu asistente por voz: ')
            audio = r.listen(source)

            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio,language='es_ES')
                print('Has dicho: {}'.format(text))
                print(text)
                if "Encender Luz Principal" in text:
                    return luzPrincipales()
           
            except:
                print('No te he entendido')
```

Esa es la función que llama a la primera función pero no lo hace, agradecería muchísimo si me ayudaran

Comment: Hola. En tu código la función que es llamada debe estar definida primero. Por ejemplo, defines `f`, luego defines `g`, entonces `g` puede llamar a  `f`, pero `f` no puede llamar a `g`

Comment: Hola, gracias por ayudarme si tienes razón, pero la función `Luzprincipales` esta definida desde antes  de `EscucharNevy`

Comment: entendí mal tu texto en el código, le daré otra revisada

Comment: tengo dos dudas, `audio = r.listen(source)`  cuándo deja de escuchar? puedes darle un `print("audio entendido")` después de esa linea para tener certeza que el programa no se ha quedado esperando una entrada de audio, luego puedes  verificar tu `print(text)` para ver si de hecho se cumplirá  `"Encender Luz Principal" in text`. Prueba con un IDE que te permite debugear, si no tienes eso entonces puedes poner varios `aux = óinput("dummy line" )`  o `print` para ver en qué lineas entra tu codigo. Además agrega un else que imprima algo como "comando no encontrado" (1/2)

Comment: ...(2/2)  ya que la secuencia `try` no te imprimirá  algo si es que no encuentra `"Encender Luz Principal" in text`

Answer (score 1):

lo mas probable es que el texto que devuelve `r.recognize_google(audio,language='es_ES')` es todo en minúsculas y cuando haces:

```py
"Encender Luz Principal" in text
```

te esta dando falso ya que `Encender Luz Principal` es diferente de `encender luz principal` por lo que nunca se ejecuta el llamado de la función `luzPrincipales()`.

PD: hubiera dejado esto en un comentario pero no tengo la reputación suficiente